# Noise problem in `media9` package

Tags: beamer, animations, media9

[image: VDO]

Source code:

```
\documentclass[t,ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\usepackage{media9}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\includemedia[
    activate=pageopen,
    width=5cm,height=5cm,
    addresource=elliptic_flow.flv,
    flashvars={
        source=elliptic_flow.flv &
        autoPlay=true &
        loop=true
    }
]{}{VPlayer9.swf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

VDO from request:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23715281/elliptic_flow.flv

This noise problem is occurred with `media9` package, the first round of my video plays very fine but from the second round forward the noise come. Note that this video run on `VLC` very fine.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Could you make the video file available for download somehow?

Comment: @AlexG Please take it above.

Comment: Converting the file with [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/) to MP4 as described in the [`media9` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf#section.1) and using that instead of the FLV video file seems to fix the problem on my machine (Windows 8.1, Adobe Reader 11.0.10). Here is the converted file: [`elliptic_flow.mp4`](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=19101264834990813019)

Comment: I don't know why when i tried to convert it to MP4 it became to MPEG-4 on MacOS X. but thank you for you mp4 file it's work!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comment